# Touchpad sensitivity decreases after suspend

Tags: touchpad, synaptics, libinput

It's the first time I'm asking a question here but I've checked tons of forums looking for the answer, be sure.

My machine is ThinkPad X1 Carbon 2014.

I'm having a fresh install of 17.10 (this problem also existed on 17.04 but did not on 16.04 LTS).
After booting the machine everything works fine. Then I close the lid, the machine suspends, I open it and touchpad sensitivity falls for scrolling and tapping. So I literally have to use more force to make it all move while the cursor itself moves as before! And even with more force scrolling behaves differently with dashes and breaks.

On 17.04 it went even further and tapping options disabled at all!

I checked the internet. Now it's clear to me that touchpad driver has changed from synaptics to libinput. I've tried to substitute libinput with synaptics as said in the ArchWiki, well nothing changed. I even don't know what influences touchpad sensitivity and how it can be changed after suspend.

UPD: Well I've checked that
    modprobe -r psmouse
    modprobe psmouse

works. So I only need to learn how to start these command automatically after suspend.

Hope you know the answer.